# Object returned by service in Angular1.x ES6 app won't show up in template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn ES6 by creating an Angular 1.x app using ES6. I am trying to retrieve an array of Recipe objects and display them in a template, but I can't seem to get them to show up.

Here are the relevant files:

app.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

// Import app config file
import Config from './config/app.config';

// Import templates file
import './config/app.templates';

// Import functionality
import './recipes';

// Create application
angular.module('recipeApp', [
  uiRouter,
  'templates',
  'helloTech.recipes'
])

angular.module('recipeApp').config(Config);
```

app.config.js

```
function Config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'RecipesCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      templateUrl: 'recipes/recipes.html',
      title: 'Recipes',
      resolve: {
        recipes: function(RecipesService, $state) {
          return RecipesService.getAll().then(
            (recipes) => recipes,
            (err) => $state.go('home')
          )
        }
      }
    });
}

export default Config;
```

recipes.service.js

```
export default class RecipesService {
  constructor($http) {
    'ngInject';

    this._$http = $http;
  }

  getAll() {
    return this._$http({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/recipes/all',
      method: 'GET',
    }).then((res) => res.data.recipes);
  }
}
```

recipes.controller.js

```
export default class RecipesCtrl {
  constructor(RecipesService) {
    'ngInject';

    this.name = 'Recipes';
  }
}
```

recipes.html

```
<section class="recipes-list">
  <h1>Recipes</h1>
  <p>{{ $ctrl.name }}</p>

  <div class="recipe-card" ng-repeat="recipe in $ctrl.recipes">
    <h2 ng-bind="recipe.name"></h2>
  </div>

</section>
```

The `{{ $ctrl.name }}` works correctly, but not the recipes and ng-repeat; what am I missing here? The template is loading correctly, I'm not getting any errors, and the recipes are being successfully retrieved from the backend.

I'm also open to moving the retrieval out of the `resolve` in app.config.js and into recipes.controller.js if that's what's needed?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the service has been injected into the controller, the resolved object has not been. Additioanly you have to expose it to the view. You need to do something like in your controller:

```
export default class RecipesCtrl {
  constructor(RecipesService, recipes) {
    'ngInject';
    this.recipes = recipes;
    this.name = 'Recipes';
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Even when I get rid of resolve in the Router and call the service within the controller it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

My service was returning an undefined object; instead of `res.data.recipes` it needed to just be `res.data`.